# How to do this complex search query in flask?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to implement an 'advanced search', but I'll keep it a bit simpler for the sake of this question.

How it works so far:

```
@app.route('/advanced_search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def advanced_search():
    form = AdvancedProductSearch()   # this is a SelectMultipleField
    countries = ['Canada', 'France', 'Mexico', 'Nigeria']
    form.categories.choices = [(c,c) for c in countries]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        countrydata = form.countries.data
        res = models.Product.query.filter(models.Product.country.in_(countrydata)).all()
        # Now I have my search results, what do I do with them?
    return render_template('advanced_search.html', title='Advanced Search', form=form)
```

My plan was to have to have another view: `advanced_search_results`, which should be used for rendering the results, but I don't know how it should work.

```
@app.route('/advanced_search_results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def advanced_search_results(query):
    #what to do?
    return render_template('advanced_search_results.html', title='Search Results')
```

I can think of two ways of proceeding:

1) Somehow pass all the rows of data in res to the `advanced_search_results()` view, but I don't see how I can do that.

2) Use a redirect to pass the desired search query to `advanced_search_results()` and do the db search there. I'm also not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return the necessary view:

```
res = models.Product.query.filter(models.Product.country.in_(countrydata)).all()
# Now I have my search results, let's send them back
return render_template('advanced_search_results.html', title='Results',
                       results=res)
```

Then, in your view you can loop over the results as you would for any other list of models:

```
{% for result in results %}
  {{ result.name }}<br>
  {{ result.country }}<br>
  <hr noshade>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, if you want to host it at another URL, just change the `action` of the form on the `advanced-search` page to point at `advanced-search-results`:

```
<form action="/advanced_search_results" method="post">
    {# etc ... #}
</form>
```

then you can validate the search and either display the results or redirect the user with an error message:

```
@app.route('/advanced_search_results', methods=['POST'])
def advanced_search_results():
    form = AdvancedProductSearch()
    countries = ['Canada', 'France', 'Mexico', 'Nigeria']
    form.categories.choices = [(c,c) for c in countries]
    if not form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("There were errors with your submission")
        return redirect(url_for('advanced_search'))

    countrydata = form.countries.data
    res = models.Product.query.filter(models.Product.country.in_(countrydata)).all()
    return render_template('advanced_search_results.html',
                           title='Search Results',
                           results=res)
```

This makes your `advanced_search` method simpler:

```
@app.route('/advanced_search', methods=['GET'])
def advanced_search():
    form = AdvancedProductSearch()   # this is a SelectMultipleField
    countries = ['Canada', 'France', 'Mexico', 'Nigeria']
    form.categories.choices = [(c,c) for c in countries]
    return render_template('advanced_search.html', title='Advanced Search', form=form)
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot I can `render_template()` from within this view. My only problem with this is that the user will still be at http://localhost:5000/advanced_search. Can that be changed?

Comment: Ah, this looks much better. But do we have to fill in the `choices` for `form.categories` in both views? The form doesn't seem to validate otherwise... Can we get around this? My `choices` will come from some database queries, but they will be redundant in the `advanced_search_results()` view.

Comment: If you are going to validate the request, you'll need to pull the choices where you are validating things.  You can add caching to avoid the extra DB trip.

Comment: How does one add caching? I can replace `if not form.validate_on_submit():` with `if not form.is_submitted():` and it works, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: No, the caching would be at the lookup level so that getting the form choices would populate the cache on the first request and all subsequent requests would pull the form choices from a Python process local data structure.  That's a different question entirely though :-)